# Unable to find class within a class capybara

Tags: selenium, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, chrome-web-driver

My html code is :

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
```

I tried:

```
1. find(:xpath, "//span[@class='sr-only']").click


2. page.find('.sr-only',visible: false).click
```

but was not able to find element 'sr-only'. How to find it?

Exception I got is:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError:
   element not visible
```

**Note** Using chrome webdriver + selenium

Comment: Could share if there is any exception occurred??

Comment: Try as `page.find('.close',visible: false).click` and let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Capybara doesn't find non-visible elements (which anything with a class of 'sr-only' usually is), and even when you tell it find non-visible elements (through the visible: false (or :hidden/:all) option) you won't be able to click on the element because there would be no way for a user to click on a non-visible option.  It seems like you want to click on the close button, so if you're using Capybara 2.10+ you should be able to do

```
click_button(class: 'close')
```

if using an older Capybara you should be able to do

```
find('button.close').click
```

Comment: That fixed my issue. However, is there a changelog for 2.10?

Comment: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/History.md - may be 2.9 the class option was added in